# User_Sessions in vertica

Tags: vertica

I have a requirement where in I have to capture user_session details for last few months. When I query user_sessions table, I have information only for last three, four days. Is there anyway, we could get the user_sessions details for last 6 months?

Thank you,
Sadagopan

Answer (score 1):

User_session is a view on top of 3 diffract data collectors tables ,  data collectors tables   include info about many events and activity’s exists on Vertica , this info is being persists on disk  with some default retention period . 
You have two main options to have 6 months historical view of your sessions 
1.  Change the setting of the retention period of  relevant DC tables to 6Mounts 
2.  Develop a script or process that will run each few days and merge the content of the user_session to user define local table .

For options #1 you need to run the below API for each one of the DC tables (be careful using this  options require extra disk space on the Vertica side )  .

SELECT set_data_collector_time_policy('SessionEnds', '1 day'::interval);
SELECT set_data_collector_time_policy('SessionStarts', '1 day'::interval);
SELECT set_data_collector_time_policy('RuntimePriorityChanges', '1 day'::interval);

Comment: Thanks @elirevach. We were doing option #2 where a script updated a user table everyday incrementally. Due to some migration, this script stopped running and we are trying to get the details for last few months. If we turn on option#1, this will take effect only going forward from today. Correct?